# Global functions to post and get API data in swift

Tags: function, api, post, get, global

I am trying to make my POST and GET API request methods global so that I need not repeat the call procedure repetitively. For this, I created a swift file and made two functions for POST API and GET API, but can't figure out how to pass data from calling class to the called class, and return back the response to the calling class. My code which needs to be integrated in a separate swift file is :

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://api.quickblox.com/users.json")!)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("0.1.1", forHTTPHeaderField: "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version")
    request.setValue(tokenSet, forHTTPHeaderField: "QB-Token")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: [])

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }

    task.resume()
```

I need to pass API Url and a request data in the form of a dictionary, to, say postApiRequest() and getApiRequest() methods. How do I create swift file for the same and call it elsewhere.